# Reports automatically and forcefully filtered by owner role (Winter 19)

Tags: reporting, filters, role-hierarchy

Since Winter 19 release all of our reports are now being filtered by owner role automatically. We can't find a way to clear the filter, and we can't find an entry in the release notes. A Salesforce case is open, but maybe the community is faster, with a workaround. (I will post any updates to the case here.)

Now it's not possible for our users to see for example cross role Opportunities, which of course changes all aggregations of amounts and therefore dashboards --> nervous bosses.

Comment: This is a known issue, see this thread in the [Release Readiness community](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer (thanks to David) from Liz Skaates from Salesforce in the [Release Community (Oct 8th)](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oku), talking about what the issue and workaround is, and that they're trying to roll back part of the release. Our support case remains unanswered.

Liz Skaates (Salesforce):

> Hi all, apologies for this surprise change in behavior in Winter '19.
>   Here is a summary of the intent of the change, as well as our plans
>   for addressing the behaviors you're seeing:
>   - The intent of the change: We wanted to address the issue of "null" or no role being selected for report types that use role hierarchy
>   filters. For CRTs, even if you chose to filter by a null role
>   hierarchy, the default was to filter by the running user's role. We
>   wanted to make it such that a "null" role selection is the same as
>   choosing the top of the role hierarchy, which should behaviorally be
>   the same.
>   - The actual effects of the change: The change we introduced in Winter '19 did not properly address the scenario of orgs where there are
>   multiple top-level roles defined, when using "All opportunities" with
>   the role hierarchy filter. The filter would only be able to use one of
>   the top-level roles in the filter. This meant that not all
>   opportunities would actually be returned
>   - What we're planning to do: We are planning to roll back the Winter '19 change until we can properly support an "all roles" selection for
>   the role hierarchy filter. This is not an easy roll-back, though, so
>   it will take some time (potentially a couple weeks).
>   - Workaround: In the meantime, as we try to roll this back for Winter '19, the workarounds that are (and have already been mentioned in this
>   thread by others): (a) add a single top-level role manually to your
>   role hierarchy and move existing roles underneath the new role, (b)
>   use Classic for now.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled through this for a few hours and it is still a major issue that I would like to see a fix for. I was able to work around this by creating a report type Users with Opportunities Joined on the Opportunity Owner.

This allowed me to filter to All Users which will show all opportunities since the Opportunity Owner is never null in my case.

This is still confusing for users since the fields like Name will be User Name vs Opportunity which is what they would expect.